# Common resources for all projects in a solution

Tags: vb.net

I have solution with few projects included.
One of project is common library project which contain mostly reusable code and functions which shares all other projects under solution and which is referenced to all included projects.
In that project I also have resources like are images and icons and I can access those resources from other projects like that:

```
Me.Icon = myCommonDll.My.Resources.backup__add__16x16
```

Question is:
Can it be done somehow that those common resources in myCommonDll will be actual resources for other projects in solution so when I click to "Image" or "Icon" in properties window in designer I get listed images or icons which are present in myCommonDll.My.Resources and how to do that?

Comment: Did you make your resource file public?

Comment: I don't know what you think but in myCommonDll.My.Resources.Images and myCommonDll.My.Resources.Icons there are many files. I set "Access Modifiers" to "Public" from related combobox if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yes that was what I mean, but after commenting, I realize that even if you set that Access Modifier to public you can not see resources from another project set image using resource in designer, I think it can not be done

Comment: Then alternative would be to keep images on filesystem/disk but I still can't believe that NET solution can't have common resource. But also, I am aware that "everything is possible even what is (normaly) impossible" with MS products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  This is primarily for VS versions prior to VS2008 which did NOT allow you to change the access level modifier for REsources.  Other alternatives were external tools or Reflection, but still did not expose resources to the designer.

DLL resources are available at runtime fairly easily but not in the designer.  You need to write a small broker in the DLL to fetch images by name.  DLL:

```
Public Class ResMgr
 ' depending on what else is in the DLL, can just add to an existing class
 Public Function GetImage(imgName As String) As Image
      Return My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imgName)
 End Function

 '' alternatively declare it SHARED eg
 ''Public Shared Function/Property GetImage As Image

End Class
```

App:

```
MyRM = New ResMgr

thisImg = New Image
thisImg = MyRM.GetImage(userImg)
```

If you construct it as `Shared` method, it is just:

```
thisImg = ResMgr.GetImage(userImg)
```

If you want, you can expose an Enum in the DLL to act as a resource manifest:

```
Public Enum ResImg
      Image1                     ' use the names of the images
      Backup52
      Flag_FR
      Flag_RUS
      ...
End Enum
```

The DLL function can either act on ResImg and use a big case statement, or you can use `[Enum].GetNames` to convert/get an array of image resource names.

Comment: Hi Plutonix. I don't see a point of that since if I reference a dll and "Imports" it as namespace then I have accessible images at design and runtime if I know exact names which I often don't know. This seems as a great lack of visual studio projects!

Comment: Its actually an alternative to making the DLL resources public. Also, in VS versions prior to VS 2008, there was not an access level modifier for Resources, so one was left with Reflection or something like this to get at them (`InternalsVisibleToAttribute` didnt work with NET2 and VB combo).  Didnt know what VS version you had.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .vbproj file and update the two statements below by adding the common directory path of your shared resource files. Good Luck!

```
<Compile Include="<common Dir>\My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>

<EmbeddedResource Include="<common Dir>\My Project\Resources.resx">
  <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```